# Android TableLayout: columns go from right to left on device, while on editor - from left to right

Tags: android

I don't know what causing this issue:

[on android studio editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1rdg.png)

[on actual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTAPb.png)

as you can see, columns start from right instead of left.

please help!

thanks

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: http://textuploader.com/52dbm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device is probably set to a language or locale that reads Right to Left, instead of Left to Right.  Meanwhile, your computer is set to a language or locale that reads Left to Right.

In such a case you will find the device automatically inverts your layout without you having to do any work to make it so.

Comment: and if i want it to look the same on device set to rtl and on device set to ltr? thanks

Comment: Don't make any changes to the app or the layout.xml.  Just make sure your phone is set to a locale and language that reads Left to Right.

Comment: That's a problem. I'll have users that use right to left languages, and i want to support them too.

Comment: It's not a problem.  Your app is already supporting them automatically, as you see.